# ruby sort_by with_index modulo

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
input = ["a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d","a","b","c","d"]
```

I want this:

```
result = ["a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d"]
```

I tried this:

```
input.sort_by.with_index do |piece, index|
  index%3
end
```

I got this:

```
["a", "d", "c", "b", "c", "b", "d", "a", "d", "b", "a", "c"]
```

why?

Comment: it should be `index%4`

Comment: Another way is `input.each_slice(4).to_a.transpose.flatten`.

Comment: You can get from `input` to `result` with `result = index.sort` ? Not sure I understand the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If look at `index % 3`, you get:

```
input     "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" "a" "b" "c" "d" 
index      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
index % 3  0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
```

and if you group them by `index % 3`, you get:

```
input     "a" "d" "c" "b"
index % 3  0   0   0   0 

input     "b" "a" "d" "c"
index % 3  1   1   1   1

input     "c" "b" "a" "d"
index % 3  2   2   2   2
```

Since sort in Ruby is not stable, when you sort them by `index % 3`, you get:

```
[
  <some permutation of "a" "d" "c" "b">,
  <some permutation of "b" "a" "d" "c">,
  <some permutation of "c" "b" "a" "d">,
]
```

which is what you got.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input.sort_by.with_index do |piece, index|
  index%3 + (index.to_f / input.count)
end
```

**How did we get here?**

The OP's solution is close but, as mentioned by @sawa, `index%3` gives us only 0, 1, or 2. Ruby's unstable sort will mix up items in those groups.

It doesn't have to be this way. Instead, can fudge these sort keys so ruby has no choice but to sort it right. We just need a fudge-factor that is:

- always increasing but
- always small enough won't accidentally bump us into a new group (i.e. < 1)

**Episode One: A shot in the dark**

Consider, fudging it by `index`:

```
input.sort_by.with_index do |piece, index|
  index%3 + index
end
```

This might seem stupid, but it does meet 1/2 criteria: always increasing, it's just to big. We can fix this.

**Episode Two: Ruby Redemption**

We know `index < input.count`, so if we just divide both sides by `input.count` we get `index.to_f / input.count <`, which is exactly what we want (but don't forget to convert to a float)!

```
input.sort_by.with_index do |piece, index|
  index%3 + (index.to_f / input.count)
end
```

**Bonus**

I think this solution is clever, but for that very reason don't actually use it in public:

```
input.sort_by.with_index do |piece, index|
  index%3 - 1.to_f / (1 + index)
end
```

Comment: Where is `with_index` documented?